# How can i take data for Fragment activity from an activity, in android?

Tags: android, fragment

I have an fragmentActivity to visualize a map, now i need to take the coordinates (latitude and longitude) from another activity. How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If another activity is starting your map fragmentActivity , then you can simply pass those coordinated inside Intent Bundle. For example:

```
Intent intent;
intent.putExtra("KEY_LATITUDE", 51.1232112);
intent.putExtra("KEY_LONGITUDE", 51.1232112);
```

in your map fragmentActivity, you will read those values inside onCreate using getIntent and appropiate methods.

If this is the other way around, and your map activity is showing some other activity to ask for coordinates, then use onActivityResult and startActivityForResult mechanism.